# hardhat fork, unable to call balanceOf

Tags: contract-deployment, evm, web3.py, hardhat

I have been able to successfully fork the mainnet of Avalanche locally via Hardhat and interact with existing smart contracts.

Starting today though, without any changes in scripts, I tried the exact same thing, starting with `npx hardhat node --network hardhat` entered in the terminal and tried wrapping test ETH (Avalanche). The balance did go down but the balane of wETH (wAVAX) in the metamask wallet did not increase.

Then, I tried calling the simple balance function `print(contract.functions.balanceOf(address).call())`, which resulted in the following error.

```
raise BadFunctionCallOutput(msg) from e
web3.exceptions.BadFunctionCallOutput: Could not transact with/call contract function, is contract deployed correctly and chain synced?
```

I think I have seen this error a while back when my chain Id was not set correct. But given that my `hardhatconfig.ts` worked perfectly fine till yesterday, I am not sure what could have happened.

The call functions and my wrapping scripts do work perfectly on the mainnet.

Comment: On Metamask go to Settings->Advance->Reset account, sometimes with forking the nonces dont match so that happens.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error and what solved it for me is that i reset my Metamask

setting -> Advance-> Reset account

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).